# how to integrate pull to refresh feature to android app

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I made a android app in that it has a listview with rss feeds .so I am trying  to implement pull to refresh in my app for loading but I searched for a library I am getting link of [[https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh]](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh%5d) this .But I don't know How to integrate this library to my android app and I didn't find any jar related to this.please help me.

Comment: checkout this link..
http://www.tutecentral.com/android-pull-to-refresh/

Answer (score 2):

Recently, Google has implemented `PullToRefreshView` into its support v4 library. You can find at [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html)

The implementation is very simple.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}">

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/list_view"
      android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

In your class, you can implement something like this.

```
mSwipeView.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright, android.R.color.holo_green_light,
    android.R.color.holo_red_light, android.R.color.holo_orange_light);
mSwipeView.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override public void onRefresh() {
          // Your action here
    }
});
```

And cancel it by

```
mSwipeView.setRefreshing(false);
```

Comment: I tried this working fine but actually I want to implement pull to refresh

Comment: @peter if you really really want to use "Pull to refresh", I suggest you to try Chris Banes library ( https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh )

Comment: I am asking same thing how to integrate that library in my app

Comment: @peter there is a sample app in the repo. you can check the code https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/tree/master/sample